# How can I create a dropdown menu in Ruby on Rails from a dynamically created array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select

I am trying to create a dropdown menu in Rails from an array that is populated via API calls. Since the information I need is stored in a different application and will change each time, I don't want to create a model and store anything in my application. I create the list in one of the methods of controller classes, and cannot figure out how to render the dropdown of the list elements in the corresponding view. everything I have been able to find online seems to pertain more to creating a dropdown from a model.

Answer (score 0):

You can create select options from an array with plain values with the [`options_for_select`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select) helper.

Assuming you have the following array:

```rb
fetched_api_values = ["a", "b", "c"]
```

Doing:

```rb
options_for_select(fetched_api_values)
```

Will result in the HTML:

```html
<option value="a">a</options>
<option value="b">b</options>
<option value="c">c</options>
```

This result can be used as collection/choises argument in combination with the [`select_tag`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-select_tag) or [`select`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-select) helper.

Check out the documentation if you'd like to know how to provide a custom label.

The Rails guide [Action View Form Helpers](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) has also a section [Making Select Boxes with Ease](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#making-select-boxes-with-ease) that might be worth giving a look.